# What is this type of sink drain/plug called?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink

We recently moved into a condo, and the sinks have screw-in drain cover. We are trying to find a replacement drain cover that is able to close, but I can't figure out what the type of drain is called to see if this exists!

The drain itself has a plus-shaped brace that sits about an inch in, with a threaded hole in the middle. It looks a lot like a bathtub drain, but the threading of the hole is slightly different.

The cover is a wide metal disc with a short bar coming from the bottom which is partially threaded. I feel like this is the type of drain + cover in a lot of hotels.

[image: Image of drain and cover]

### EDIT: 7/8

I thought it might be a 'pop up click' or 'click clack' drain (as two answers suggested), and ordered a pop up stopper and bolt, but the length of the bolt is way longer than our drains (even in 'compressed' position).

The length of the stem on our drain cover is ~33mm, with ~13mm thread, while the 'pop up' we got has a 66mm bolt, with much larger thread. See image below for comparison.

[image: Comparison of Click Clack drain and our drain]

Comment: Is there a knob on the top of the cover? https://www.thespruce.com/bathtub-drain-stopper-types-2718995

Comment: Nope- no knob, just a smooth domed cover.

Comment: Does the threaded part of the cover you're holding in the pic fit the threaded part of the drain grate?

Comment: Yes- it screws in down to where the thread stops, which leaves a ~1/4 inch gap between the drain cover and the bottom of the sink. Works great for general use, but impossible to close the drain.

Comment: IMO you have somehow got the wrong cover for your drain.  I think you have a lift and turn type drain, but the cover for some other type, or perhaps some other model.  Do you perhaps have an overflow cover that has a manufacturer's name on it, or any other type of identifying feature?  Do you hopefully have an access panel on the other side of the wall from the tub drain?

Answer (score 1):

I have always heard those type are called pop up drain plugs , it looks like yours is missing the rubber seal. If when you press it it drops down and press again it pops up you probably only need to find the rubber seal.

Comment: I dunno.  Maybe it's just the picture perspective, but the disc looks way bigger than the hole in the drain.  Bigger than the drain flange, even.

Comment: The disc is very large - approx 2.75in/69mm. It overhangs the edges of the drain by quite a bit.

Comment: The one I have in my tub is similar the rubber is narrower than the cap itself. If it pops up and down I don’t see a seal, it is a simple function it needs a seal even if the cap is 1 foot around to hide the drain and things that collect on them the rubber is narrower than the cap in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Search `popup click drain plug`.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=popup+click++drain+plug&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: Good thought; unfortunately it looks like popup drain plugs are way longer than the space available in our drain (added edits and comparison picture with popup drain plug to the original question)